# Mutability of Hashmaps in java

Tags: java

I am trying to build a giant HashMap of HashMaps. I ran into problems with mutability where I kept modifying the elements that was already added to the map. I ended using this approach, although it does what it is supposed to to wondering there might be a better way to do this

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> s = null;

        // process 1
        s = new HashMap<>();
        s.put("foo", "bar");
        s.put("foo1", "bar");
        s.put("foo2", "bar");
        s.put("foo3", "bar");
        map.put("m1", (HashMap<String, String>) s.clone());

        // process 2
        s = new HashMap<>();
        s.put("9", "bar");
        s.put("10", "bar");
        s.put("11", "bar");
        s.put("12", "bar");
        map.put("m2", (HashMap<String, String>) s.clone());

        // process 3
        s = new HashMap<>();
        s.put("99", "bar");
        s.put("103", "bar");
        s.put("112", "bar");
        s.put("121", "bar");
        map.put("m3", (HashMap<String, String>) s.clone());

        for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            HashMap<String, String> value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.print("");
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `clone` in the above code, as you're creating a new `HashMap` in each "process" anyway. It would only be a problem if you removed the `s = new HashMap<>()` part.

Comment: Instead of manually creating a map of maps, you might want to use Guava's [HashBasedTable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html) which does exactly that while abstracting away the dirty work from you

Comment: Where is your mutability problem? Your keys and values are `String`. (sorry if it's obvious, it's still early morning here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you create a new `HashMap` for each inner reference there is no need to `clone` it. What you are doing here is simply putting a new object to a reference:

`s = new HashMap<>();`

So in short each `HashMap` you create this way will be a different object and the `s` variable holds a reference to the current one you are working with.